# Problems when plotting points in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm having some problems when trying to plot two groups of points into a chart in MATLAB. I've created two matrices which represent the groups separately, one group of circles and the other of crosses. The outcome should be like the picture below:

[image]
The code which creates the two groups is this:

```
circles = [1 1; 2 1; 2 2; 2 3; 2 4; 3 2; 3 3; 4 1; 4 2; 4 3];
crosses = [1 2; 1 3; 1 4; 2 5; 3 4; 3 5; 4 4; 5 1; 5 2; 5 3];

plot(circles, 'ro');
hold on
plot(crosses, 'b+');
hold off;
axis([0,6,0,6]);
```

But this code plots a messy chart, similar to the image below:

[image]

What could be wrong with the plotting?

Comment: Per [the documentation for `plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html), calling `plot` with one input matrix plots the entire matrix as `y` values, where the `x` value is the [linear index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/) of the data point. If you remove the `axis` call you will see this reflected in your plot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Plot` typically accepts two dimension arguments. If one is supplied, then the elements get plotted corresponding to their index.

> PLOT   Linear plot.
>       PLOT(X,Y) plots vector Y versus vector X. If X or Y is a matrix,
>       then the vector is plotted versus the rows or columns of the matrix,
>       whichever line up.  If X is a scalar and Y is a vector, disconnected
>       line objects are created and plotted as discrete points vertically at
>       X.
>
> **PLOT(Y) plots the columns of Y versus their index.**
>       If Y is complex, PLOT(Y) is equivalent to PLOT(real(Y),imag(Y)).
>       In all other uses of PLOT, the imaginary part is ignored.
>
> Various line types, plot symbols and colors may be obtained with
>       PLOT(X,Y,S) where S is a character string made from one element
>       from any or all the following 3 columns:

So since you need to provide both `x` and `y` separately, you could easily solve your problem like so:

```
circles = [1 1; 2 1; 2 2; 2 3; 2 4; 3 2; 3 3; 4 1; 4 2; 4 3];
crosses = [1 2; 1 3; 1 4; 2 5; 3 4; 3 5; 4 4; 5 1; 5 2; 5 3];

plot(circles(:, 1), circles(:, 2), 'ro');
hold on
plot(crosses(:, 1), crosses(:, 2), 'b+');
hold off;
axis([0,6,0,6]);
```

**This solution is defining the x and y dimensions explicitly**, so there should not be such a confusion with the plot and it will generate it exactly as you would like it to be.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to help, no problem.

Comment: Only one more question: I'm using the feedforwardnet function to separate the groups using MLP neural networks. How can I plot the divisory line (net) together with the graph?

Comment: @GabrielMachado do not ask questions after your initial question has been answered. If this answer helped, accept it (as you have done), possibly upvote it and leave it be. Open a new question with your additional question.